# How to prevent socket timeout error when printing to ESC/POS with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the `Flutter` package `esc_pos_printer 1.5.0` to print to a thermal receipt printer. It works fine if the printer is online but I get a socket timeout when it is not, even when I nest the code in a try / catch block.

Normally I expect the printer will be connected by Ethernet but it could also be WiFi.

The package author recommends using `andrey-ushakov/ping_discover_network`
 but that package says in the `README`

> Could be used to find printers (for example, on port 9100) and any
>   other devices and services in local network.
>
> The device should be connected to a Wi-Fi network. wifi package allows
>   to get the local IP address / network subnet.

Here is the error:

> ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110

Here is my code:

```
  try {    

    Printer.connect('192.168.1.100', port: 9100).then( (printer) {

      printer.println('welcome',
        styles: PosStyles(
          height: PosTextSize.size2,
          width: PosTextSize.size2,
        ));

      printer.cut();
      printer.disconnect();
      }
    );
    }    
    catch (e) {    
      print(e);
      // do stuff
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Printer.connect` method returns a Future which means the work is done asynchronously.

Since the code execution is not on hold by `await`, the execution completes the method and returns to caller method without caring about the execution of code inside the block in `.then()`.

What you can do is following:

1. you can use Future's `catchError` and catch the exception without waiting for the `.then()` block execution:

```dart
    Printer.connect('192.168.1.100', port: 9100).then( (printer) {
      printer.println('welcome',
        styles: PosStyles(
          height: PosTextSize.size2,
          width: PosTextSize.size2,
        ));

      printer.cut();
      printer.disconnect();
      }
    ).catchError((e) {
      //handle the exception the way you want, like following
      print('Caught error when processing: $e');
    });
```

2. Keep the try catch as it is and just add `await` for the method call:

```dart
try{
   final printer = await Printer.connect('192.168.1.100', port: 9100);
   printer.println('welcome',
        styles: PosStyles(
          height: PosTextSize.size2,
          width: PosTextSize.size2,
   ));

   printer.cut();
   printer.disconnect();
  } catch (e) {    
      print(e);
      // do stuff
  }
```

Source for Future based error handling:https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: With 1. above I get 'E/flutter ( 9624): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'SocketException' has no instance getter 'error'.
E/flutter ( 9624): Receiver: Instance of 'SocketException'
E/flutter ( 9624): Tried calling: error

Comment: this is just an example code, you can do whatever you want to handle the exception. Let me update the answer to remove any confusion.